# Laravel Eloquent, return JSON with "belongsTo" object?

Tags: orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models with a one-to-many relationship.

```
class User extends ConfideUser {

    public function shouts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Shout');
    }

}

class Shout extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

This seem to work fine.
BUT, How do I get this to return the users object nested in the shout objects?
Right now it only returns all my Shouts, but I have no access in the JSON to the belonging user model.

```
Route::get('api/shout', function() {
    return Shout::with('users')->get();
});
```

This just returns this JSON, with no user object for every shout:

```
[{"id":"1","user_id":"1","message":"A little test shout!","location":"K","created_at":"2013-05-23 19:51:44","updated_at":"2013-05-23 19:51:44"},{"id":"2","user_id":"1","message":"And here is an other shout that is a little bit longer...","location":"S","created_at":"2013-05-23 19:51:44","updated_at":"2013-05-23 19:51:44"}]
```

Comment: I am also building an API in Laravel at the moment, and I highly recommend looking into [resourceful controllers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) and nested resources. Here is also a nice tutorial on the topic: https://tutsplus.com/lesson/nested-resources/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

The method needs to be named user() not users() when working with "belongsTo" relationship.

Makes sense.

And seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same trouble using Laravel 5. Just wanted to add that I got it to work by using the `Model::with("relationship")->get()` method on the model.

Answer (score 2):

u can use `protected $with = ['users'];` on Class Shout and use `protected $with = ['shouts'];`.

and Give Full namespace model name

```
class Shout extends Eloquent {

   protected $with = ['users'];

   public function users()
   {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
   }
}
```

and

```
class User extends ConfideUser {

    protected $with = ['shouts'];

    public function shouts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Shout');
    }
}
```

Receive It

```
Route::get('api/shout', function() {
    return Shout::all()->toJson;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using:

```
protected $visible = ['user'];
```

Don't forget to add there relationship, to be visible in JSON